# WebView with multiple buttons to browse file in the same page

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, uiwebview

I'm working on an OSX application using Swift and a WebView.
The WebView includes 2 HTML buttons for browsing files: the first one only allows images when the second one allows multiple files selection.

The problem is that I cannot know which button was triggered when calling the webview delegate method `runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener`.

I would like to have something like that:

```
func webView(sender: WebView!, runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener resultListener: WebOpenPanelResultListener!, allowMultipleFiles: Bool) {

    let openDialog = NSOpenPanel()

    if button1 {
        openDialog.allowedFileTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    }

    if button2 {
        openDialog.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }

    // Other stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to achieve this by calling a Swift function from Javascript.
[This blog post](http://snackcoffee.me/2015/08/20/call-swift-javascript-osx/) explains how this communication works.

When the user clicks the "browse button", I catch the event and send the name of the button to the WebView from Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#MyButtonName', function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent === "MyWebView") {
        webView.setClickedButton("MyButtonName");
    }
});
```

Then in Swift:

```
// Get Javascript key
func webView(webView: WebView!, didClearWindowObject windowObject: WebScriptObject!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    windowObject.setValue(self, forKey: "webView")
}

// Call Swift selector
override class func webScriptNameForSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> String! {
    if aSelector == "setClickedButton:" {
        return "setClickedButton"
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

// Allow selector
override class func isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript(aSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
    return false
}

// Set the current clicked button from Javascript
func setClickedButton(btnName:String) {
    self.htmlClickedButton = btnName
}
```

Now I can get the clicked button in my delegate method:

```
if (self.htmlClickedButton == "MyButtonName") {
    openDialog.allowedFileTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
}
```

I'm not sure about this solution, it's working but it doesn't look like the best way to achieve my issue.
So I let this thread opened for any better suggestions.